# R - calculating the average value of previous quarter's dependent variable as independent variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I am running a logistic regression of the form:

```
model_1 <- lrm(dependent_variable ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = merged_dataset, na.action="na.delete")
```

What I would like to do is to include the previous quarter's average dependent variable as an independent variable.

My data look like:

```
> print(head(merged_dataset[,c("dependent_variable", "qy")]))
   dependent_variable      qy
1:                  0 2008 Q1
2:                  0 2008 Q1
3:                  0 2008 Q1
4:                  0 2008 Q1
5:                  0 2008 Q1
6:                  0 2008 Q1
```

where the dependent variable takes values 0 or 1, and the qy variable takes values such as 2008 Q1, 2008 Q2, .... , 2017 Q4.

EDIT:

I run the following code:

```
# function that gets the name of previous quarter
PrevQ = function(quarter = "2018 Q1"){
  ifelse(grepl("Q1", quarter), 
         paste0(as.numeric(substr(quarter, 1,4))-1, " Q4"), 
         paste0(substr(quarter, 1,6), as.numeric(substr(quarter,7,7))-1)
  )
}

# means in current quarters
merged_dataset$dep_means = with(merged_dataset, ave(dependent_variable, qy, FUN = mean))

# get names of previous quarters   
merged_dataset$prev_qy = PrevQ(merged_dataset$qy)

# merge mean of previous quarter by name of the quarter
merged_dataset$var4 = with(merged_dataset, dep_means[match(prev_qy, qy)])

print(head(merged_dataset[,c("dependent_variable", "qy")]))


print(head(cbind(merged_dataset$var4,merged_dataset$qy)))
```

which gives me

```
> print(head(merged_dataset[,c("dependent_variable", "qy")]))
   dependent_variable      qy
1:                  0 2008 Q1
2:                  0 2008 Q1
3:                  0 2008 Q1
4:                  0 2008 Q1
5:                  0 2008 Q1
6:                  0 2008 Q1
> 
> 
> print(head(cbind(merged_dataset$var4,merged_dataset$qy)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA 2008
[2,]   NA 2008
[3,]   NA 2008
[4,]   NA 2008
[5,]   NA 2008
[6,]   NA 2008
```

It seems to be changing the qy variable and only the year remains? And I get all NAs.

```
> print(head(cbind(merged_dataset$var4,merged_dataset$qy,merged_dataset$dep_means)))
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]
[1,]   NA 2008 0.1292719
[2,]   NA 2008 0.1292719
[3,]   NA 2008 0.1292719
[4,]   NA 2008 0.1292719
[5,]   NA 2008 0.1292719
[6,]   NA 2008 0.1292719


> print(tail(cbind(merged_dataset$var4,merged_dataset$qy,merged_dataset$dep_means)))
         [,1]    [,2]       [,3]
[32008,]   NA 2017.75 0.09802372
[32009,]   NA 2017.75 0.09802372
[32010,]   NA 2017.75 0.09802372
[32011,]   NA 2017.75 0.09802372
[32012,]   NA 2017.75 0.09802372
[32013,]   NA 2017.75 0.09802372
```

Comment: `indep_var <- with(merged_dataset, ave(dependent_variable, qy, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))`, then lag by quarter?

Comment: How can I then lag by quarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# function that gets the name of previous quarter
PrevQ = function(quarter = "2018 Q1"){
    ifelse(grepl("Q1", quarter), 
           paste0(as.numeric(substr(quarter, 1,4))-1, " Q4"), 
           paste0(substr(quarter, 1,6), as.numeric(substr(quarter,7,7))-1)
       )
}

# sample data
set.seed(5551)
merged_dataset = data.frame(dependent_variable = sample.int(2,6, rep = TRUE)-1, 
                            qy = rep(c("2017 Q4", "2018 Q1"), each = 3))

# means in current quarters
merged_dataset$dep_means = with(merged_dataset, ave(dependent_variable, qy, FUN = mean))

# get names of previous quarters   
merged_dataset$prev_qy = PrevQ(merged_dataset$qy)

# merge mean of previous quarter by name of the quarter
merged_dataset$var4 = with(merged_dataset, dep_means[match(prev_qy, qy)])

merged_dataset
#   dependent_variable      qy  dep_means prev_qy       var4
# 1                  0 2017 Q4 0.33333333 2017 Q3         NA
# 2                  1 2017 Q4 0.33333333 2017 Q3         NA
# 3                  0 2017 Q4 0.33333333 2017 Q3         NA
# 4                  0 2018 Q1 0.00000000 2017 Q4 0.33333333
# 5                  0 2018 Q1 0.00000000 2017 Q4 0.33333333
# 6                  0 2018 Q1 0.00000000 2017 Q4 0.33333333
```

Comment: Does this work for all quarters? Is there a way that I don't have to write the quarters `2018 Q1` and `2017 Q4` and that it automatically figures it out?

Comment: @adrCoder Yes, it should work for all quarters, try it on your data. You don't have to write the quarters, here they are just manually added when creating the sample data.

Comment: Do I just write it as you wrote it or I need to change something?

Comment: @adrCoder No need to change anything. Just skip the `#sample data` section, since you have your own data.

Comment: @adrCoder Only NAs? It returns NA's when there are no dependent_variable data for the previous quarter, like for 2017 Q3 in my answer. Could you add a reproducible example to the question?

Comment: I edited my original post. It seems to be changing the qy variable and I get all NAs?

Comment: @adrCoder I don't have your original `merged_dataset` so I can't replicate the issue. However, I see no way how could the `qy` column be modified by the code here. There is no line that modifies the `qy` column. Is original `merged_dataset` a data.frame? You may try changing it to a `data.frame`, and changing original `merged_dataset$qy` to character (if it isn't).